# Get Count of rows fulfilling a condition group by a column with min and max

Tags: mysql, group-by, having-clause

I want to get count of people who leave on time in some specific date range in an attendance scenario. For that I need total employees who marked their attendance when they left office. If an employee logged at-least two times (1 for in and 2nd for out) only then he should be counted in total employees who marked their out attendance.

```
SELECT Max(TIMESTAMP),COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id) totalCount FROM attendance , db2.psnl p WHERE Date(timestamp) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('14/05/2019', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('14/05/2019', '%d/%m/%Y') AND  employee_id=p.MyId AND p.PayRollOfficeId=3 GROUP BY DATE(TIMESTAMP) HAVING COUNT(employee_id) >=2
```

For a single employee a modified version of this query works as group by filters the employee and so count >=2 will return rows when we have at-least 2 entries against employee for any date.

[image: db data]

[image: structure]

Comment: Why are you redacting the employee ids? We need ids. They don't have to be real. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Foll query returns records of those employees who have at least logged twice a day

```
select
attendance_id,
max(timestamp) as last_entry_by_employee,
group_concat(timestamp),
count(*) as c
from
attendance
group by employee_id, date_format(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d")
having c >= 2
```